# Bootstrap Navbar Menu Items Stuck in Hamburger Menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

Here's the problem, and it's a weird one - I can copy and paste a responsive Bootstrap navbar from one project into a different one and get different results. Notably, in the first project, narrowing the window size eventually shrinks the navbar into a collapsible hamburger menu - which is what I want. Copying and pasting the same code into a different project results in the navbar menu items **always** being inside the hamburger menu. I can click it to expand and show the navbar menu items, but cannot get them to be outside the hamburger menu at any browser width.

This is more of a conceptual question I suppose. I could post my code here, but I know it works in the first project - so I don't know how helpful it would really be and don't believe it to be a syntax issue.

I thought perhaps this was being caused by a CSS override somewhere else in the project, but removing all unnecessary CSS files gives the same result. I downloaded fresh bootstrap files and replaced the ones I was using to no avail. I checked for unclosed/stray divs and there were none. I am stumped and am looking for some more ideas to try.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the both projects have the same bootstrap version. Also you say you deleted all redundant css form the project you pasted the markup into. Dit you do the same with the project you copied the markup from? You are right to narrow the problem down to identify it. Don't know BS that well. But you can also disable all js to see if it has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: And don't forget the wrapping html. See if when it is identical it solves your problem. Jus narrow it down.

Comment: @allcaps Using the same Bootstrap file as my original project fixed the navbar problem, thank you! Unfortunately I realized the reason is because my original project uses Bootstrap 3.x and the other project uses Bootstrap 2.x, which are very incompatible and resulted in breaking a lot of other things. But that answered my question.